# Pagination for Wordpress Custom Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

i am working on a news page in my custom theme, and i need to put pagination on it. I tried everything, but it doesnt seem to be working. Could someone help me with the pagination, but have to do it with qustom queries, so i can fetch post thumbnail, title and link to it.

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page'=> 4,
   'category_name'=> 'news',
   'featured' => 'false',
   'sidebar'=> 'false'
), $atts );

$the_query = new WP_Query($atts);
    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md col-xl-6">
            <div class=" mt-2 mb-2">
                <a href="#">
                <div class="latest-news__wrapper">
                    <div class=" lazyloaded">
                      <?php if(get_the_post_thumbnail()){ 
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail('',['class' => ' latest-news__thumbnail']); 
                            }else{
                                echo '<img class=" rounded-3  latest-news__thumbnail" src="'. site_url() . '/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/da084e01-7cae-3ee6-8b2e-1f0e76fd397f.jpg'.'" alt="" />';
                            }?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="latest-news__info">
                        <div class="latest-news__date"><?php the_time('j F, Y') ?></div>
                        <h4 class="latest-news__title text-color-5 lines-2">
                            <?php 
                            if (strlen(the_title('','',FALSE)) > 30) { 
                                    $title_short = substr(the_title('','',FALSE), 0, 30); 
                                    preg_match('/^(.*)\s/s', $title_short, $matches);
                                if ($matches[1]) $title_short = $matches[1];
                                    $title_short = $title_short.' ...'; 
                                } else {
                                    $title_short = the_title('','',FALSE);
                                } 
                                echo $title_short;
                                
                            ?>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [where is wordpress search pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749737/where-is-wordpress-search-pagination)

Comment: @MattHamer5 no, not really, i have to use it in a shortcode